# How to make these nested loops parallel using OpenMP?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to parallel this code using OpenMP but still the serial code is faster.

```
#define NUM_THREADS 4
        
void Calculate(double *N, double *M, double *K, const long length)
{
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(NUM_THREADS)
      
    #pragma omp for collapse(2)
    for (long i = 0; i < length; i++)
        for (long j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            K[i * length+ j] = 0.0;
            for (long k = 0; k < length; k++)
                K[i * length+ j] += N[i * length+ k] * M[k * length+ j];
        }
}
```

The function argument length has the value `5`.

Comment: What do you mean by "but no luck"?

Comment: Still the serial code is faster

Comment: Do you notice any speed difference at all? If not, are you sure that OpenMP is active? On some platforms, you [may have to explicitly activate it in the compiler settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69701133/12149471).

Comment: Yes I notice the speed difference.

Comment: How big is `length`?

Comment: as @Laci pointed out, you need to tell us the value of length

Comment: The length is 5

Comment: Note that using a temporary variable and acessing `K[i * length+ j]` only once can be beneficial (especially in parallel code).

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: If you want this code to be faster for 5x5 matrices, you need not to use threads. The synchronization time will be much bigger than the time to complete the work (at least 1 order of magnitude, probably even two). You can speed up a bit the computation using SIMD instructions and loop unrolling.

Comment: I want to try with 1000 How should i do it in parallel

Comment: When `length=1000`, this is a significantly different problem. The best solution is to use a BLAS library which are highly optimized since decades by experienced programmers (eg. OpenBLAS, BLIS, MKL, etc.). This is simpler, faster and safer. If this is an homework, then please read [this](https://gist.github.com/nadavrot/5b35d44e8ba3dd718e595e40184d03f0) first. There are also plenty of question already posted on StackOverflow about how to do a general matrix multiplication using OpenMP.

Comment: If your objective is to learn how to use OpenMP you're going in the right direction - parallelising loop-intensive code is about the first step on that journey.  But don't get hung up on performance issues until you have larger problem sizes to tackle. And only pay attention to the advice to use BLAS when you have learned enough about OpenMP to understand why you will never write a code for matrix multiplication as fast as an architecture-appropriate BLAS library.  Well, not until you are the author of that library anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to do it using OpenMP and BLAS if yes how?

Comment: Some BLAS use OpenMP internally. You cannot control precisely how they do that though. Note that you could mix a BLAS code with your own parallel implementation using tiles and by disabling the parallel version (to avoid the over-subscribtion of threads). This is what LAPACK libraries does to speed up they computation. It is often not as fast are using a parallel BLAS in one call though.

Answer (score 3):

There is very little point in creating 3 additional threads in order to perform only 125 multiplication operations in total.

The overhead of creating these threads is significantly higher than performing the calculations serially. Also, even if the threads already exist, it is still not worth it, because [thread synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)#Thread_or_process_synchronization) is expensive, too.

The threads must be synchronized at the start and at the end of every `#pragma omp for` construct. This synchronization is likely also more expensive than performing the calculations serially.